# Linear Transformation in $\mathbb{Q}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^3$ such as $(1,2,-1) \in Ker(f)$ , $f(1,-1,0) = (3,1,2)$ and $Im(f)$ has the equation $x-y-z=0$.

I have to calculate the matrix of $f$ in the basis $B = \{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$.

How could I solve it?

Comment: what do you mean when you say Image of $f$ has the equation $x-y-z=0$?? And what is **Linear  App**?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik In French, "application" means function, so I'm guessing the OP means linear transformation.

Comment: @SpamIAm : Oh.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First take the basis $A = \{(1, 2, -1), (1, -1, 0), (1, 1, 3)\} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$. 
We have $f(v_1) = (0, 0, 0)$ and $f(v_2) = (3, 1, 2)$. Since $\text{Im}(f)$ is the $2$-dimensional space $W = \{(x, y, z):\, x -y - z = 0\}$, the value of $f(v_3)$ must lie in $W$ but is not proportional to $f(v_2) = (3, 1, 2)$. That's not enough to determine $f$, though. Given $f(v_3)$, apply a change of basis from $A$ to $B$ to get the required matrix.

Comment: Why you take $(1,1,3)$ in the basis A?

Comment: It completes the partial basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$.

Comment: I know, but you has chosen $(1,1,3)$. If I take any vector which is independent with the others, is it right?

Comment: Sure, but the choice of $v_3$ is unimportant. This particular choice happens to be orthogonal to the other two.

Comment: Ok, other question, how you calculate $f(v_3)$ if you don't know $f$?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm saying: It isn't uniquely determined.